# Need 'logo page' before wordpress page!

Tags: logo, customization

I made this website for my client using WordPress. It's all great but now he's asked me that when someone loads the website, before all the WP goodness, there's a page showing just the logo, then you click the logo and go to the main page.

I'm thinking I could either do this by changing WP's index to some other name and have the actual index file be the logo thing etc; or have a pop-up* on the actual WP index that darkens the rest of the page, then you click the logo and it's gone, allowing you to navigate the page normally. It would have to appear only the first time the user loads the page and not when you 'come back' to it from another page.

*Like when you click a screenshot here panic.com/coda for example.

Can anyone help me with either option or show me a new one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell him that doing so is bad for SEO and no one has done this since 1998.

Comment: You know what, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a simple HTML-page for displaying the logo and set this file as the default directory index. So if a user requests the domain without specifying an actual target on the server (something like /index.php) the logo-file is shown.

To specify a page as default-index, you can use [the `DirectoryIndex`-directive for the Apache server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) in an .htaccess-file:

```
DirectoryIndex logo.htm index.php
```

This would load the logo.htm (if present, otherwise load the index.php) if you call the page via the domain only.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies:

- check for the cookie and define a constant in your functions.php:

  ```
  if(!is_user_logged_in() && !isset($_COOKIE['seen_logo'])){
    setcookie('seen_logo', 1,  ...);
    define('SHOW_LOGO', true);
  }
  ```
- do your magic in the index.php / home / template:

  ```
  if(defined('SHOW_LOGO')){ ...  } else { ... }
  ```

Comment: My browser (Opera) is configured to ask me whether to accept a sites cookies or not. I never accept cookies from any sites automatically, only if I really want to login somewhere. So this solution would display the logo on every single page-call.

Comment: Unless of course you set it to accept the cookie automatically for sites you trust....